# How to combine android Media Projection with React Native?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, expo

I want to capture screenshoot from a react native App, I am using expo ejected application (`npx expo prebuild`) to use the feature of expo updates. So expo has their own way that it can create a local module. by `npx create-expo-module@latest --local` this is the [link](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/get-started/). when a local module is created say I want to create `my-module` locally, the task will be to expose a function named `captureScreenshots` and that will return the captured image uri. The image should be captured by [using android media projection](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/media-projection). A dedicated github repo is available on [github](https://github.com/sankar2389/ScreenshotNative-Media-Projection.git) that is a native mobile app written on Java.

To capture screenshot there is available package named `react-native-view-shot` but that can not be usable in this case, because that one just capture screen of that application only. It should be captured by `virtualDisplay` mentioned on `MediaProjection`. Is there any availale package that can do this way and can work with react native?

Or anyone did this implementation before?

Thanks